# Summing from one point of an array to another point of the same array in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, variables, sum

I was wondering how you can sum from one point of an array to another point, for example:

array = [1,3,5,6,1]

assuming i is a moving variable, for example

i = 2

assuming k is a moving variable, for example

k = 4

The solution I'm looking for is to sum from array[2] to array[4], so 5+6+1 = 12

I've tried using (array[i]..array[k]).reduce(:+) but it doesn't seem to work.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost! But you're creating a range between two integer array values when you want to be indexing an array!

```
array[i..k].reduce(:+)
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution given by @glennmcdonald is the normal way to do a partial sum, but it does create another array:

```
array[first_index..last_index]
```

If that array is sufficiently large, you may prefer or be required to compute the sum without creating a new array.  Here are two of many ways you could do that:

```
def sum_range1(array, first_index, last_index)
  (first_index..last_index).reduce(0) { |tot,i| tot+array[i] }
end
```

or this:

```
def sum_range2(array, first_index, last_index)
  array.each_with_index.reduce(0) { |tot,(n,i)|
    tot + ((first_index..last_index).cover?(i) ? n : 0) }
end     

arr = [1,3,5,6,1]
sum_range1(arr, 2, 4) #=> 12 
sum_range2(arr, 2, 4) #=> 12
```